# Setting notification_priority in firebase admin go client

Tags: android, firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

As Per firebase document, we can set the parameter **notification_priority** to determine message priority.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification

```
{
  "title": string,
  "body": string,
  "icon": string,
  "color": string,
  "sound": string,
  "tag": string,
  "click_action": string,
  "body_loc_key": string,
  "body_loc_args": [
    string
  ],
  "title_loc_key": string,
  "title_loc_args": [
    string
  ],
  "channel_id": string,
  "ticker": string,
  "sticky": boolean,
  "event_time": string,
  "local_only": boolean,
  "notification_priority": enum (NotificationPriority),
```

I am trying to use firebase admin go client but when I see the message struct, I cannot see that element

Struct Defined is as follows:
https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/messaging#AndroidNotification

```
type AndroidNotification struct {
    Title        string   `json:"title,omitempty"` // if specified, overrides the Title field of the Notification type
    Body         string   `json:"body,omitempty"`  // if specified, overrides the Body field of the Notification type
    Icon         string   `json:"icon,omitempty"`
    Color        string   `json:"color,omitempty"` // notification color in #RRGGBB format
    Sound        string   `json:"sound,omitempty"`
    Tag          string   `json:"tag,omitempty"`
    ClickAction  string   `json:"click_action,omitempty"`
    BodyLocKey   string   `json:"body_loc_key,omitempty"`
    BodyLocArgs  []string `json:"body_loc_args,omitempty"`
    TitleLocKey  string   `json:"title_loc_key,omitempty"`
    TitleLocArgs []string `json:"title_loc_args,omitempty"`
    ChannelID    string   `json:"channel_id,omitempty"`
    ImageURL     string   `json:"image,omitempty"`
}
```

Is there any discrepancy in firebase documentation and struct or am I missing something?
Issue is, message are delivered to device but no sound or on screen display if device is sleeping. ( Happening on one plus 7 pro, only sometimes)

I checked the events using following commands

```
   1.  Dial *#*#426#*#* to open the FCM Diagnostics page.
   2.  Tap the EVENTS button to show the event log.
   3.  Check whether the message was delivered to the device. There should be a log entry reading
```

and saw that youtube message are coming with **HIGH** priority and priority of my messages is shown as **UNKNOWN**.

How I can send message with high priority as described in documentation?

Comment: Have you tried setting the priority in the config? https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/messaging#AndroidConfig

Comment: Thanks Gavin , I will check that , Need to know the difference between these two fields. Priority at **android config** and Priority at **AndroidNotification**

Comment: Using the client, it looks like you can only send a `Message`. The `Message` struct has a field for `AndroidConfig`. I assume that's how you'd set the priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on `notification_priority`:

> Set the relative priority for this notification. Priority is an indication of how much of the user's attention should be consumed by this notification. Low-priority notifications may be hidden from the user in certain situations, while the user might be interrupted for a higher-priority notification. The effect of setting the same priorities may differ slightly on different platforms. Note this priority differs from AndroidMessagePriority. This priority is processed by the client after the message has been delivered, whereas AndroidMessagePriority is an FCM concept that controls when the message is delivered.

This parameter is currently not available in the Go SDK. Feel free to file a feature request in the GitHub repo.

Comment: I have raised it there, instead of feature request , can this be treated as high priority bug? Need to have fix in actulal repo otherwise my automated build will fail if I do anything custom on firebase admn go. My automated build process fetches the firebase go sdk from github every time for creating docker image.